# how to make the string dynamically depending in the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make the string dynamically using user input then i want to loop this to the list of first name
for example:

I have a list of this firstname

```
let firstnameList = ["Jan", "Mark","Doe"]
```

then i have this message from user input

example GUI:

[image]

```
let message = "Hello {firstname}"
```

then the `{fistname}` in the string will be replace by the names on the list

example output

```
message = Hello Jan 
message = Hello Mark
message = Hello Doe
```

Comment: In terms of the looping, without context it's hard to say, what kind of "output" are we talking about? List of strings? List of elements with that text in them? For embedding dynamic values inside strings, use template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through your array like so:

```js
let firstnameList = ["Jan", "Mark", "Doe"];
for (let firstName of firstnameList) {
    //In here you can access the current first name by using the newly created variable firstName
    console.log('Hello ' + firstName);
    // Or
    console.log(`Hello ${firstName}`);
}
```

Check out string concatenation and template literals if this is new to you.

To replace the placeholder like {firstname} in the message you can use

```js
let message = 'This is {firstname} and I am hungry.'

function fillPlaceHolders(rawString) {
    return rawString.replace('{firstname}', 'my replace string');
}

console.log(fillPlaceHolders(message));
```

Comment: this is correct but how to get the {firstname} in the string ? the firstname is not static the user can either input {firstname} {lastname} {address}

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to add a name to the list of names? firstnameList.push('Peter'); or for that matter firstnameList.push(document.getElementById('hereGoesTheIdOfYourInput').value);

Comment: i mean the user will input somethig like this https://i.imgur.com/7CZ44Cf.png

Comment: then once submited the {firstname} will get replace by the names in the string

Comment: Oh so you want the user to be able to use variables inside of their messages?

Comment: How do you plan on choosing which of the firstnames the output should contain? I mean the user only uses a variable called {firstname} and you have multiple first names to choose from.

Comment: yes i will use all those firstname like what you did in the looping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227670/discussion-between-traidos-and-corioste).

Comment: thanks! i have 1 last question in the chat

Comment: i cant seem to reply in the chat the list i provided is just an example what i have is a list of object for example ```[{fistname: jan, lastname: janlastname, address: "blabla"} ...and so on] so i use the first element

Comment: my problem now is how can i get the {firstname} in the string like a wild card that starts with '{' and end with '}'

Comment: if you can't see the chat anymore, check this [Snippet](https://codepen.io/Traidos/pen/QWKPeMa) I made for you. 
I don't understand what you are trying to ask here. Maybe ask it in your native language and I try to understand that?

Comment: Do you mean you don't only want to replace the three examples you provided but anything that is in between '{' and '}'? 
You would have to use regular expressions.
The replace would look like this with a regular expression
```'abcDEFghi'.replace(/{.+?}/g, replaceValue);```

But with this, you would replace all the variables at once. Since you don't have any logic on where you get your values from I don't know how to show you more relevant stuff for you

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```js
let firstnameList = ["Jan", "Mark", "Doe"];

firstnameList.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(`Hello ${item}`);
});
```

Comment: this is correct but how to cut the string so that it get that output this is a user input ```"Hello {firstname}"``` and the message is not static

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get that.

Comment: for example the user will input this https://i.imgur.com/7CZ44Cf.png